# Key error when trying to drop rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

```
for i in [train]:
   if(i.creation_date>i.sell_date):
    train.drop(train.index[i], inplace=True) 

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), 
a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Getting this error when I try to execute this code, train is a pandas dataframe and creation_date and sell_date are labels of columns.
I want to delete the rows where creation_date>sell_date"
Can someone please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `for i in [train]`, it gives you one item, the `train` dataframe. You want to iterate through the rows of the `train` dataframe instead:

```
for i, row in train.iterrows():
  if(row.creation_date > row.sell_date):
    train.drop(train.index[i], inplace=True)
```